# How to find equivalent of Oracle's privileges in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a user in Oracle for which the permissions given are `CONNECT` and `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE`.

How do you find the equivalents when setting up a similar user in SQL Server?

Comment: I found this.... [http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/23/sql-server-get-permissions-of-my-username-userlogin-on-server-database/](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/23/sql-server-get-permissions-of-my-username-userlogin-on-server-database/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server the right to "CONNECT" is given at the instance level.  You'll find this right assigned to the login.  The ability to view the database catalog is given at the database level by assigning the "VIEW DEFINITION" right to the database or the schema.